# (Autohotkey) Getting empty response by websocket with Autohotkey. I have no idea what's wrong in my code

Tags: websocket, autohotkey

I am trying to get dictionary through websocket with Autohotkey. Unlike the successful example, mine gets wrong just not getting any answer. I think it's supposed to give me string made as dictionary. It seems like well connected as I see no error message. Just receiving empty string.

Is it something concerned with UTF and encode/decode stuff? I don't see the problem here. Hope I can get any answer. I am stuck. Thanks

```
#Include WebSocket.ahk

New HelperClass("wss://api.upbit.com/websocket/v1")

class HelperClass extends WebSocket
{
    OnOpen(Event)
    {
        DataToSend := "[{""ticket"":""test1243563456""},{""type"":""trade"",{""type"":""trade"",""codes"":[""KRW-BTC"", ""KRW-ETH""]}]"
        this.Send(DataToSend)
    }
    
    OnMessage(event)
    {
        MsgBox, % "Received a message!:`n" Event.data
        this.Close()
    }
    
    OnClose(Event)
    {
        MsgBox, Websocket Closed
        this.Disconnect()
    }
    
    OnError(Event)
    {
        MsgBox, Websocket Error
    }
    
    __Delete()
    {
        MsgBox, Exiting
        ExitApp
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could link the documentation where this this websocket specified? Quite impossible to say anything about it without knowing what it is and how it should be used.

Comment: I hope this is what you were asking for. https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=35117  I only changed the address up there.

Comment: Yes, I know that one. I wrote the example code and explanation for you in your last question haha. But the websocket you're trying to use. Where's its documentation, gotta know from somewhere what and how you're supposed to send into and and how it's supposed to respond.

Comment: Ok, I took a look at the json payload you're trying to send. It's most definitely broken. It is not valid json syntax. So that'll need fixing at the very least. But still don't know what it's supposed to contain.

Comment: Oh,man. Didn't realize that. was very helpful for understanding and seemingly it worked. But the value returned has got a problem.

Comment: https://global-docs.upbit.com/docs/websocket-    You might be able to find the part I referred at 25% from the top of the page.

Comment: I see. The problem seems to be that they return a `promise`, instead of just plan text. Would require some extra steps to get that done, and I don't have time to try to do that right now myself. Maybe you'd have more luck with their [REST Api](https://global-docs.upbit.com/docs/rest-api-)? In one of your older questions you used one successfully.

Comment: Oh that might be a hint for me. I don't fully undetstand what those mean but I now I think which way to try. Last time was such a big help for me and I reckon you spent quite a time. Thanks for the guide again. That's more than enough.

Comment: Now I understood what you meant. The rest API was somewhat reading one by one stuff, so I thought I'd rather try with another one. I will start with 'promise' first. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will not help as you want, because the original link is not live, just a little help in debugging.

[JSON.ahk is there](https://github.com/G33kDude/AutoHotkey-JSON/tree/1899578d0f0ea394804421b5a5319238238f81e1)

```
#Include <WebSocket>
#Include <JSON>

New HelperClass("wss://api.upbit.com/websocket/v1")

class HelperClass extends WebSocket
{
        OnOpen(Event)
        {
                DataToSend := "[{""ticket"":""test1243563456""},{""type"":""trade"",{""type"":""trade"",""codes"":[""KRW-BTC"", ""KRW-ETH""]}]"
                this.Send(DataToSend)
        }
        
        OnMessage(event)
        {
                MsgBox, % "Received a message!:`n" Event.data
                this.Close()
        }
        
        OnClose(Event)
        {
                MsgBox, Websocket Closed
                this.Disconnect()
        }
        
        OnError(Event)
        {
                MsgBox, Websocket Error
        }

        OnData(Data)
        {
            msgbox, % "OnData: " JSON.Dump( Data ) 
        }
    
    _Event(EventName, Event)
    {
        msgbox, % EventName " " Event
    }
        __Delete()
        {
                MsgBox, Exiting
                ExitApp
        }
}
```

This shows the type of information, sended by ws server, and if it is "data" OnData will show you its content.